# MariaDB system_time_zone format (abbreviation vs IANA) on Linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, timezone, mariadb

I'm trying to understand how MariaDB/MySQL **system_time_zone** global variable is set in case it's not provided by configuration.

So on Linux machines we configure server time zone by linking */etc/localtime* to the entry from IANA tz database, f.e. *Europe/Helsinki*, which has *EEST* time zone abbreviation:

```
$date
Tue Aug  2 17:27:38 EEST 2016
```

After start of MariaDB with default configuration we see this:

```
MariaDB> show global variables like '%time_zone%';
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| system_time_zone | EEST                |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM              |
```

So *system_time_zone* is set abbreviation, not IANA name. 
The problem is that after running *Connector/J* with Java 8 and *useLegacyDatetimeCode=false* most of server timezones are causing

```
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: The server time_zone 'EEST' cannot be parsed.
```

during startup, because value of *system_time_zone* is searched in IANA tz database by current implementation of *Connector/J* (we used 1.3.6):

> org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils#getTimeZone

```
public static TimeZone getTimeZone(String id) throws SQLException {
    TimeZone tz = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    ...
    return tz;
}
```

*java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone* is using IANA tz database under the hood.

Some abbreviation are present in IANA database, f.e. MST or HST, but obviously it's not reliable to match abbreviation to time zone name from IANA list.